# find limit of $ \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (2,0)} \frac{x+y-2}{x^2+y^2-4} $

Tags: limits, analysis

I have a problem with finding a limit of this:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,0)}\frac{x+y-2}{x^2+y^2-4}$$

I was thinking about using this: $\;\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant\dfrac{1}{2|xy|}$

I also looked at some sequences to determine, whether the limit exists or not and my intuition is that it exists.
Any ideas how to calculate this limit?

(Sorry, there was a mistake in the first question)

Comment: The limit at $(0, 0)$ is simply $\frac{0+0-2}{0+0-4} = \frac 12$. Did you state the problem correctly?

Comment: Maybe the limit is at $(2,0)$ or $(0,2)$...

Comment: Approach along the line $y = x-2$ and see the magic(?)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer After answering,  I see that your approach is simpler. $=\frac 1x$ and limit doesn't exist , indeed .

Comment: @lonestudent Feel free to include my comment in your answer if you feel it's easier. I like your answer, but cannot upvote it (or the question) because I've actually exhausted my $40$ votes for the day. I will vote it, and the question, up tomorrow. I was surprised to not find a duplicate and it's a good enough question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, we have that

- for $x=t+2$ and $y=t$ with $t\to 0$

$$\frac{x+y-2}{x^2+y^2-4}=\frac{2t}{2t^2+4t}=\frac{1}{t+2} \to \frac12$$

- for $x=t^2+2$ and $y=t$ with $t\to 0$

$$\frac{x+y-2}{x^2+y^2-4}=\frac{t^2+t}{t^4+5t^2}=\frac{t+1}{t^3+5t} \to \pm \infty$$

therefore limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x-2=z$ as $z\to 0$, then you have :

$$\lim_{(y,z)\to(0,0)}\frac{y+z}{z^2+4z+y^2}$$

Then let $y=a\sin x, \thinspace z=a\cos x$ with $x≠\pi \frac {2n-1}{2}$ as $a\to 0$, we get :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{a\to 0}\frac {a(\sin x+\cos x)}{a^2+4a\cos x}&=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac {\sin x+\cos x}{a+4\cos x}\\
&=\frac {\tan x+1}{4}\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

This means that, the limit doesn't exist .